# Freeing memory in dynamic buffers containing dynamic buffers

Tags: c, malloc, free

Say I have:

```
char **search_terms = malloc(sizeof(char *) * number_search_terms);
for (i=0; i < number_search_terms; i++)
    search_terms[i] = malloc(MAX_LINE_LEN);
```

When I free this memory, is it enough to do

```
free(search_terms)
```

or do I have to free each element in the buffer first, like this:

```
for (i=0; i < number_search_terms; i++)
    free(search_terms[i]);
free(search_terms);
```

Comment: Its just you have to free array of pointers first followed by pointers themselves. Simply undo how you have allocated memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`free` has no knowledge of your data structures.  You pass it a block of memory that was previously allocated with `malloc` (or `calloc` or `realloc`), and it frees that block of memory and nothing else.

So, to avoid leaking memory, you must have exactly as many calls to `free` as to `malloc`.  There are two reasons for this:

1. In C, memory managed on the heap (with `malloc` and `free`) is largely treated as a black box.  There is no mechanism in the language that allows the library functions to know what you've stored in the memory, so `free` cannot traverse your array for you.
2. Automatically traversing a data structure makes a policy decision for you: the components of the data structure are treated as a whole and should be freed as a whole.  In general, this is not true, and C avoids making these decisions for you.  For example, your substrings may, for performance reasons, be allocated as a large, contiguous block that you free at one time.  C allows you a great deal of flexibility in this, but it also requires that you actively manage heap memory.

Answer (score 3):

You have to free each buffer first, and then free the bigger buffer. `free` will never traverse a tree to see if part of your data happens to be a pointer to other `malloc`ed data.